# Creating a new column for -ve values from the existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to write logic for this in SQL Server:

```
Voucher #   Name   Amount 
-------------------------
 123        ABC     910
 123        ABC    -910
 224        XYZ     600
```

Expected output

```
Voucher #    Name     Amount   - (Amount)
-------------------------------------------
 123         ABC       910       -910
 224         XYZ       600         -
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.  You definitely have something in mind, but the data is too simplistic.  What if multiple rows have "910"?

Comment: Helo Sir,I need a new column for the -ve amounts instead of storing them in a seperate row based on that particular voucher

Comment: Are all positive values on left, all negative on right?

Comment: What if there are multiple positives and negatives? Do you pick the topmost(based on a criteria), or do same positives and same negatives are aggregated?

Comment: Is there only 1 positive and 1 negative value for each name?

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation is really simple here. No need to query the same table over and over.

```
select Voucher
    , Name
    , Amount = sum(case when Amount > 0 then Amount else 0 end)
    , [-Amount] = sum(case when Amount < 0 then Amount else 0 end)
from YourTable
group by Voucher
    , Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, try it
Group by negative and positive amount and make a left join

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Voucher varchar(10),
    Name    varchar(100),
    Amount  int 
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    Voucher,
    Name,
    Amount
)
VALUES
(123,'ABC',910),
(123,'ABC',-910),
(224,'XYZ',600)

SELECT t1.Voucher, t1.Name, t1.Amount , ISNULL(t2.Amount,0) AS [(-Amount)] FROM (
SELECT t.Voucher, Name, Sum(t.Amount) Amount 
FROM @tbl t
WHERE t.Amount > 0
GROUP BY t.Voucher, t.Name) t1 Left JOIN 
(SELECT t.Voucher, Name, Sum(t.Amount) Amount 
FROM @tbl t
WHERE t.Amount < 0
GROUP BY t.Voucher, t.Name) t2 ON t1.Voucher = t2.Voucher
```

Answer (score 0):

If for each `(Voucher, Name)` there exists only 1 positive `Amount` and 0 or 1 negative `Amount` then with a self join:

```
select t.*, tt.amount NegativeAmount
from tablename t left join tablename tt 
on tt.voucher = t.voucher and tt.name = t.name and tt.amount < 0
where t.amount > 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3278086ab8659a854778d53a44177895).
Results:

```
> voucher | name | amount | NegativeAmount
> ------: | :--- | -----: | -------------:
>     123 | ABC  |    910 |           -910
>     224 | XYZ  |    600 |
```